# How is it possible that $H_p(\Bbb{S}^n)\cong H_p(\Bbb{S}^{n-1})$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

My Algebraic Topology book says the following:

> For $\Bbb{S}^n$, $H_p(\Bbb{S}^n)=\Bbb{Z}$ for $p=\{0,n\}$, and $H_p(\Bbb{S}^n)=0$ otherwise.
>
> Also, by Mayer-Vietoris, $H_p(\Bbb{S}^n)\cong H_p(\Bbb{S}^{n-1})$.

How can both be true? Shouldn't $H_{n-1}(\Bbb{S}^n)=0$ and $H_n(\Bbb{S}^n)=\Bbb{Z}$?

Comment: I'm sure it's just a typo, and should read $H_{p-1}(S^{n-1})$.  You get the associated Mayer-Vietoris sequence by considering fattened upper and lower hemispheres of $S^n$.  Their intersection is essentially the equator, which is $S^{n-1}$.

Comment: @JoshKeneda- You're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typo.  It means to say $H_p(S^n)\cong H_{p-1}(S^{n-1})$.  (Actually, this is only true if you used reduced homology, or require $p>1$.)

Comment: You're right. Thanks!

Comment: @Ayush Khaitan, Please consider accepting this answer if it solved your problem. That way the system won't consider this as an unanswered questions.